Number of unique numbers in a vector with replacement
If I get a vector $x$ of length $\ell\geq n$ that contains random draws of $n$ numbers and know that all $n$ numbers appear at least once in such vector, how many numbers appear exactly once in this vector in expectation?
To be more precise: $x$ is drawn with replacement but I know that the vector has at least one copy of each of the $n$ numbers.
The question is related to the existing questions Probability distribution of the number of unique elements when picking $m$ items from $n$ with replacement
Expected number of unique items when drawing with replacement
but it is not the same. I wonder if the solution using Stirling numbers of the second kind is also useful in this case.

One needs to specify the random model more precisely. Is $\ell$ fixed in advance or does it depend on the draws that occur? Do you keep sampling and discarding attempts that don't contain all $n$ numbers until you get one that does?

You probably want to specify explicitly that there are $l$ independent draws from a uniform distribution on the set ${1,\ldots, n}$ and that $l>n.$ Then the question can be reformulated in terms of conditional distribution.

I provided some clarifications above. I saw the suggestion of reformulating in terms of conditional distributions but I must be very thick because I didn't get it.

The number is a random variable. Would you be satisfied with the mean of that variable, or do you need the full distribution before you can approve an answer?

The mean of that variable would be more than enough

Using combinatorial  classes as in  Analytic Combinatorics
by  Flajolet  and Sedgewick,  we  have  the following  class
$\mathcal{V}$ of  vectors drawn from $[n]$  where each value
occurs at least once
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{V} = \textsc{SEQ}_{=n}(\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
This gives the EGF
$$F(z) = (\exp(z)-1)^n.$$
In particular the count of these vectors is
$$\ell! [z^\ell] (\exp(z)-1)^n
= n! {\ell \brace n}.$$
Now mark singletons to get
$$\mathcal{V} = 
\textsc{SEQ}_{=n}(\mathcal{U}\times \textsc{SET}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z}) + 
\textsc{SET}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
We get the bivariate GF
$$Q(z,u) = (\exp(z)-z-1+uz)^n.$$
For the count of singletons we find the EGF
$$\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} Q(z,u) \right|_{u=1}
= nz (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}.$$
Extract the coefficient on $z^\ell$
$$\ell! [z^\ell] n z (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}
= \ell (\ell-1)! [z^{\ell-1}] n! \frac{1}{(n-1)!} (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}
\\ = \ell \times n! {\ell-1\brace n-1}.$$
It follows that the expectation is
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[S] = \ell {\ell-1\brace n-1} {\ell\brace n}^{-1}.}$$
Using the asymptotic
$${\ell\brace n} \underset{\ell\rightarrow\infty}{\sim}
\frac{n^\ell}{n!}$$
we get with the pair of Stirling numbers
$$\ell \frac{(n-1)^{\ell-1}}{(n-1)!}
\frac{n!}{n^\ell}$$
which means that
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[S] \sim \ell 
\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\ell-1}.}$$
We can in fact compute the $r$th factorial moment by differentiating
$Q(z,u)$ $r$ times. We get
$$\ell! [z^\ell] n(n-1)\cdots(n-(r-1)) z^r (\exp(z)-1)^{n-r}
\\ = \ell(\ell-1)\cdots (\ell-(r-1)) (\ell-r)!
n! [z^{\ell-r}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n-r}}{(n-r)!}
\\ = r! {\ell\choose r} n! {\ell-r\brace n-r}.$$
This means that
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[S(S-1)\cdots (S-(r-1))]
=  r! {\ell\choose r} {\ell-r\brace n-r} {\ell\brace n}^{-1}.}$$
As a sanity  check $S$ is of course at  most $n$, when $r\gt
n$ we thus get zero for  the moment in question which agrees
with the first Stirling number.  When $r=n$ we get zero when
$\ell\gt r$  which is $\ell\gt  n$ and indeed the  number of
singletons is  at most $n-1$  in that case which  gives zero
for  the  moment.   When  $r=n$ and  $\ell=r$  we  get  $n!$
contributing vectors (only contribution  is when $S=n$ so we
permute the $n$  unique values) with the  statistic equal to
$n!$  which  is  indeed $n!{n\choose  n}n!{n-r\brace  n-r},$
giving $n!$ as the value of the moment.

Thank you, just checked with simulations, very accurate. Would it be possible to use the same approach when the vector of length l has *at least one singleton?

@fox I have added an answer where I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Additional statistics as per  request. We ask about
the conditional expectation of the number of singletons
given  that  we  know  the  vector  has  at  least  one
singleton. Counting  the vectors with no  singletons we
get the EGF
$$A(z) = (\exp(z)-z)^n.$$
Extracting coefficients we find with $\ell\ge n$
$$\ell! [z^\ell]
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} z^{n-q} \exp(qz)
= \ell! \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} [z^{\ell+q-n}] \exp(qz)
\\ = \ell! \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
(-1)^{n-q} \frac{q^{\ell+q-n}}{(\ell+q-n)!}.$$
Therefore the count of the admissible vectors is
$$n^\ell -  \ell! \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q}
\frac{q^{\ell+q-n}}{(\ell+q-n)!}
= \ell! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-1-q}
\frac{q^{\ell+q-n}}{(\ell+q-n)!}.$$
The contribution from the number of singletons is found
by differentiation  of the  marked mixed GF  (this will
give a zero contribution from the vectors containing no
singletons)
We have
$$B(z) = (\exp(z)-z+uz)^n.$$
Differentiate and evaluate to get
$$\ell! [z^\ell] n z \exp(z(n-1))
= n \ell! [z^{\ell-1}] \exp(z(n-1))
= n \ell (n-1)^{\ell-1}.$$
We thus have for the desired expectation
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[S] = \frac{n (n-1)^{\ell-1}}{(\ell-1)!}
\left[ \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-1-q}
\frac{q^{\ell+q-n}}{(\ell+q-n)!} \right]^{-1}.}$$
Using the dominant term of the sum we find for $\ell\to\infty$
$$\mathrm{E}[S] \sim \frac{n (n-1)^{\ell-1}}{(\ell-1)!}
\left[n \frac{(n-1)^{\ell-1}}{(\ell-1)!}\right]^{-1}$$
This says that
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\mathrm{E}[S] \sim 1.}$$
The formula is exact when $n=2.$
We  can also  evaluate  the count  of  vectors with  no
singletons in terms of Stirling set numbers, we get
$$\ell! [z^\ell]
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} (z-1)^{n-q} (\exp(z)-1)^q
\\ = \ell! [z^\ell]
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} q! (-1)^{n-q}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-q} (-1)^{n-q-p} {n-q\choose p} z^p (\exp(z)-1)^q/q!
\\ = \ell!
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} q!
\sum_{p=0}^{n-q} (-1)^p {n-q\choose p}
\frac{1}{(\ell-p)!} {\ell-p\brace q}
\\ = n! \sum_{q=0}^n
\sum_{p=0}^{n-q} (-1)^p
\frac{1}{(n-q-p)!} {\ell\choose p} {\ell-p\brace q}.$$

Thanks for this! I do no t think it makes sense that the expected number of singletons is roughly one because we know there is at least one singleton, but maybe I am misunderstanding.

Try to run some simulations. I believe it is true. I also computed the exact expectation for small values of the parameters with Maple and they matched. With $\ell$ large the majority of vectors have instance count of every value close to $(\ell-1)/(n-1)$, leaving just the one singleton.
